# How to update column of spark dataframe based on the values of previous record

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have three columns in df

```
Col1,col2,col3

X,x1,x2

Z,z1,z2

Y,

X,x3,x4

P,p1,p2

Q,q1,q2

Y
```

I want to do the following
when col1=x,store the value of col2 and col3
and assign those column values  to next row when col1=y
expected output

```
X,x1,x2

Z,z1,z2

Y,x1,x2

X,x3,x4

P,p1,p2

Q,q1,q2

Y,x3,x4
```

Any help would be appreciated
Note:-spark 1.6

Comment: this would be too difficult to solve in a distributed framework.. How will you know which one is whose previous X?

Comment: even i had that doubt ...but thought may be there would be something similar to lag function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach using Window function with steps as follows:

1. Add row-identifying column (not needed if there is already one) and combine non-key columns (presumably many of them) into one
2. Create `tmp1` with conditional nulls and `tmp2` using `last/rowsBetween`  Window function to back-fill with the last non-null value
3. Create `newcols` conditionally from `cols` and `tmp2`
4. Expand `newcols` back to individual columns using `foldLeft`

Note that this solution uses Window function without partitioning, thus may not work for large dataset.

```
val df = Seq(
  ("X", "x1", "x2"),
  ("Z", "z1", "z2"),
  ("Y", "", ""),
  ("X", "x3", "x4"),
  ("P", "p1", "p2"),
  ("Q", "q1", "q2"),
  ("Y", "", "")
).toDF("col1", "col2", "col3")

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val colList = df.columns.filter(_ != "col1")

val df2 = df.select($"col1", monotonically_increasing_id.as("id"),
  struct(colList.map(col): _*).as("cols")
)

val df3 = df2.
  withColumn( "tmp1", when($"col1" === "X", $"cols") ).
  withColumn( "tmp2", last("tmp1", ignoreNulls = true).over(
    Window.orderBy("id").rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)
  ) )

df3.show
// +----+---+-------+-------+-------+
// |col1| id|   cols|   tmp1|   tmp2|
// +----+---+-------+-------+-------+
// |   X|  0|[x1,x2]|[x1,x2]|[x1,x2]|
// |   Z|  1|[z1,z2]|   null|[x1,x2]|
// |   Y|  2|    [,]|   null|[x1,x2]|
// |   X|  3|[x3,x4]|[x3,x4]|[x3,x4]|
// |   P|  4|[p1,p2]|   null|[x3,x4]|
// |   Q|  5|[q1,q2]|   null|[x3,x4]|
// |   Y|  6|    [,]|   null|[x3,x4]|
// +----+---+-------+-------+-------+

val df4 = df3.withColumn( "newcols",
  when($"col1" === "Y", $"tmp2").otherwise($"cols")
).select($"col1", $"newcols")

df4.show
// +----+-------+
// |col1|newcols|
// +----+-------+
// |   X|[x1,x2]|
// |   Z|[z1,z2]|
// |   Y|[x1,x2]|
// |   X|[x3,x4]|
// |   P|[p1,p2]|
// |   Q|[q1,q2]|
// |   Y|[x3,x4]|
// +----+-------+

val dfResult = colList.foldLeft( df4 )(
  (accDF, c) => accDF.withColumn(c, df4(s"newcols.$c"))
).drop($"newcols")

dfResult.show
// +----+----+----+
// |col1|col2|col3|
// +----+----+----+
// |   X|  x1|  x2|
// |   Z|  z1|  z2|
// |   Y|  x1|  x2|
// |   X|  x3|  x4|
// |   P|  p1|  p2|
// |   Q|  q1|  q2|
// |   Y|  x3|  x4|
// +----+----+----+
```

[UPDATE]

For Spark 1.x, `last(colName, ignoreNulls)` isn't available in the DataFrame API.  A work-around is to revert to use Spark SQL which supports ignore-null in its last() method:

```
df2.
  withColumn( "tmp1", when($"col1" === "X", $"cols") ).
  createOrReplaceTempView("df2table")
  // might need to use registerTempTable("df2table") instead

val df3 = spark.sqlContext.sql("""
  select col1, id, cols, tmp1, last(tmp1, true) over (
    order by id rows between unbounded preceding and current row
    ) as tmp2
  from df2table
""")
```

Comment: I am getting some exception "error: overloaded method value last with alternatives:" and i am removing second parameter of from  last("tmp1",ignoreNulls = true) then I am getting this exception "38: error: value unboundedPreceding is not a member of object org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window"

Comment: I am using spark 1.6

Comment: You can replace `Window.unboundedPreceding` with `Long.MinValue`.  Unfortunately `last(colName, ignoreNulls)` isn't available prior to Spark 2.0.  Please see my updated answer for a work-around.

Comment: Still I am getting org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Couldn't find window function last;  let me know if i am doing somethng wrong

Comment: I don't have a Spark 1.6 environment hence can't reproduce the said problem.  To revert to using Spark SQL make sure you `import sqlContext.implicits._`.  Here's a relevant [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32905443/spark-couldnt-find-window-function) for your reference.

Comment: Thanks @Leo It  solved my requirement in spark 2.0 but we r still using 1.6 in production.  Can we do it using pure scala code  running in distributed mode...is it good idea???

Comment: Glad that it helps, though I'm a little surprised that the Spark SQL work-around doesn't work in Spark 1.6.  Not sure I understand what you mean by pure Scala code in distributed mode.  If you mean using the RDD API with Scala, here's a relevant [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33621319/spark-scala-forward-fill-with-last-observation) which might be of interest.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a [lag](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@lag(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,offset:Int):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) function that requires ordering

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window.orderBy
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{coalesce, lag}

case class Temp(a: String, b: Option[String], c: Option[String])

val input = ss.createDataFrame(
  Seq(
    Temp("A", Some("a1"), Some("a2")),
    Temp("D", Some("d1"), Some("d2")),
    Temp("B", Some("b1"), Some("b2")),
    Temp("E", None, None),
    Temp("C", None, None)
  ))

+---+----+----+
|  a|   b|   c|
+---+----+----+
|  A|  a1|  a2|
|  D|  d1|  d2|
|  B|  b1|  b2|
|  E|null|null|
|  C|null|null|
+---+----+----+

val order = orderBy($"a")
input
  .withColumn("b", coalesce($"b", lag($"b", 1).over(order)))
  .withColumn("c", coalesce($"c", lag($"c", 1).over(order)))
  .show()

+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|
+---+---+---+
|  A| a1| a2|
|  B| b1| b2|
|  C| b1| b2|
|  D| d1| d2|
|  E| d1| d2|
+---+---+---+
```