# how to use window function in sqlContext in spark scala

Tags: sql, scala, hadoop, apache-spark, window-functions

I need to use window function in spark scala.
Spark version is 1.5.1 and scala is 2.11.7

There is a similar question ([Using windowing functions in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36171349/using-windowing-functions-in-spark))

But, in my case, there is no hive. I can't import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.

"By inheritance, HiveContext is actually an SQLContext" but, my case is not.

```
scala> sqlContext
res2: org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext = org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext@1136122a
```

Is there way to use window function??
thanks.

Comment: How about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32407455/spark-and-sparksql-how-to-imitate-window-function

Comment: @JustinPihony is right ! You can try to mimic window functions if you don't wish to add the hive dependency. Nevertheless, I have answered that question 3 or 4 times (1 of them is the link provided). You really need to read those answers carefully

Comment: Here is one other http://stackoverflow.com/a/36398242/3415409